# Motion Tracking a Camera Move and Zoom?

Tags: tracking

Is it possible to motion track a camera move that zooms mid way through the shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Currently is not possible to track shots with variable focal length or shots where the lens breaths too much.